# div in not centering with another div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a login page like facebook. But the login form in not getting inside the parent div(header). I decreased the width for the h1 elements but it is not working.

So what should I do so that header and login form stays side by side.

Below is my code.

```css
.header {
background: #3B5998;
height: 90px;
}

.header h1 {
color: white;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-left: 20px;
width: 40%; 
}

.log {
background: pink;
float: right;
margin-bottom: 100px;
width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Login Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="all">
</head>

<body>
<div class="header">
    <h1>ChatBook</h1>

    <div class="log">
        <form action="#" method="POST">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain more about what you want to do i mean what you have done with image or jsfiddle ? then someone can understand what is problem ..

Comment: Use bootstrap....

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox***:

```css
body {margin: 0}

.header {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  justify-content: space-around; /* horizontal alignment / also experiment with other values such as: "space-between", "space-evenly", "center" ... */
  align-items: center; /* centers them vertically */
  background: #3B5998;
  height: 90px;
}

.header > h1 {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>ChatBook</h1>
  <div class="log">
    <form action="#" method="POST">
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem the form doesn't fit is because the `<h1>` element is not floated, and although set to have a `width: 40%`, it won't allow other elements to float next to it.

All you have to do is add `float: left;` to the `<h1>` element, and you're all good to go.

Comment: It works well but after that when i'm trying to increase the parent height it is not changing

Comment: You should probably read more about how `float` works in CSS. Give the parent element the following style property to clear the float after the two floating elements: `.header:after { clear: both; }`. But this is outside the scope of your question.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, apart from flexbox use diplay:table to parent elment and display:table-cell with vertical-align : middle on child elements to vertically center.

```
.header {
background: #3B5998;
height: 90px;
display:table;
  width:100%;
}

.header h1 {
color: white;
width: 50%; 
  display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.log {
background: #3B5998;
width: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/QOBPMW

**Option 2:**
Use CSS transforms to vertical center element , by setting translateY to 50% which will position element vertically center and  make H1 element display:inline-block to make both elements align horizontally in one line

```
.header h1 {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 20px;
  width: 40%;
  display:inline-block;
}

.log {
  background: pink;
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ZajZRL

Answer (score 0):

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  background: skyblue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header .title {
  float:left;
}
.header .log {
  float:right;
  margin: 20px;
}
.header .log input{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Login Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="all">
</head>

<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="title">
      <h1>ChatBook</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="log">
        <form action="#" method="POST">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
.header {
  background: #3B5998;
  height: 90px;
  display:table;
  width:100%
}
```

because of float it will came out